# if 800k record takes 50 secs all http pending request in queue would block for 50 sec as sever become ideal

Tags: node.js, mongodb

if 800k record takes 50 secs all http pending request in queue would block for 50 sec as sever become ideal .

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

http.createServer(function(request, response) {

if (url.parse(request.url).pathname == '/search'){

    var collection = db.collection('documents');
   // suppose it takes 800k record in 40 secs all request would be block until response end
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {

      console.log("Found the following records");
      console.dir(docs);

      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      response.write(JSON.stringify(docs));
      response.end();
    });
}
else
{
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write(0 + '');
  response.end();
}
}).listen(8888);
```

Comment: Please put a question into your question.  What exactly are you asking for help with?

Comment: the concurrent is about more than 1k , you can implement cache against this collection. I have resolved similar situation , in ROR and Nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB's native nodejs driver [supports streaming](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#stream). It gives a readable stream which you can pipe to response. Optionally, write a transform stream to convert documents on the fly.

```
 collection.find({}).stream().pipe(myTransform).pipe(response);
```

This approach will not wait to load all documents in memory (`toArray()`) and then double load it (`JSON.stringify()`). It will keep forwarding data from mongdb to response, with some buffering.